# How to sort a matrix (2D array) in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to sort a 4X4 matrix (2D array) by column and row. For example:

Original matrix:

`6    2    9    4
 4    5   -1    9
 4   -2    0    7
 3    2   10    3`

Desired result:

`-2   -1    0    2
 2    3     3    4
 4    4     5    6
 7    9     9   10`

Comment: It it's an actual 2D array (and not an array of pointers), you can just use [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), and pass the address of the first element `&mat[0][0]` as the buffer address.

Comment: If it's not an array of arrays (a.k.a. a "2d array") then put all the values in a single one-dimensional array, sort that array, then put the values back into the matrix.

Comment: It looks like you are actually sorting a 1D array disguised as a 2D one. May I ask why you need this?

Comment: Use a sorting algorithm like bubble sort etc

Answer (score 2):

2D array basically uses contigous memory location, so you can sort it same as you sort 1D array

```
const int row = 4,col = 4;
int mat[row][col] = {6 ,   2 ,   9  ,  4
                    ,4 ,   5 , -1   , 9
                    ,4   ,-2 ,   0   , 7
                    ,3    ,2 ,  10   , 3};
sort(&mat[0][0],&mat[0][0]+(row*col));
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```